# I need to create an html page in netbeans

Tags: java

I am new to netbeans.
I need to design an html page.i wanted to know how can i get the drag and drop facility in netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this docs

http://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/visualwebdev/

Comment: i need to make an application using servlet only.not jsp.

Comment: @bhavna: that's almost the same as telling "I need to drive a car using steer and engine only, not wheels."